# how to alias(AS) a table in raw SQL with knex.js

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

I am using knex.js with MySql DB. I have a migration where I have to use raw SQL. My migration looks like this :

```
import * as Knex from "knex";
const brokersTable = "OriginationAdmin.Brokers";
const brokerIndividualTable = "OriginationAdmin.BrokerIndividuals";


exports.up = async (knex: Knex) => {
   await knex.schema.raw(
             `UPDATE ${brokersTable}
                 JOIN( 
           SELECT CompanyName, MIN(Id) AS Id
             FROM ${brokersTable}
            GROUP BY CompanyName )
          AS x
      ON x.CompanyName = ${brokersTable}.CompanyName
     AND isDeleted IS NULL
     SET isDeleted = CASE WHEN (x.Id <> ${brokersTable}.Id) THEN 1 END`
 );
```

when I run migrate up I get an error message:`RequestError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'`. I know the SQL Query is syntactically correct but why am I getting an error with the aliasing keyword and how do I fix it?

Edit: This most(relevant part) of the error message

```
migration file "20210822190619_de-duplicate-brokers-and-associate-individuals.ts" failed
migration failed with error: UPDATE OriginationAdmin.Brokers
      JOIN (
             SELECT CompanyName, MIN(Id) AS Id
               FROM OriginationAdmin.Brokers
              GROUP BY CompanyName
           ) AS x
        ON x.CompanyName = OriginationAdmin.Brokers.CompanyName
       AND isDeleted IS NULL
       SET isDeleted = CASE WHEN (x.Id <> OriginationAdmin.Brokers.Id) THEN 1 END
       - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
RequestError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
    at handleError (/Users/haroonAzhar/Desktop/FAL/omni-api/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:366:15)
```

The error message isn't very helpful to what the problem is.

Comment: it tells you that it is near the AS and nit that explicit position , if you gave no possibility to check what knex actually sends out enabkle general log in mysql and see what the server gets and the you can try the query in workbench , but carfuk it gets quick very big, so enable it only for debugging

Comment: There's something wrong with the subquery parentheses [`"(" ... ")"`] positions in the error message. Did you spot it?

Comment: yes, I posted the wrong error message. thankyou for pointing it out. The problem still remains.

Comment: What if you remove `) AS x` and just `) x` on the subquery? Will it have error?

Comment: yes, but the error message  is ` Incorrect syntax near 'x'.
RequestError: Incorrect syntax near 'x'` @FaNo_FN

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `knex.js` or any type of ORM for that matter but after a quick search, I understand a bit more about it. So, my next question is, have you tried (and successfully run) any mysql query that have subquery using the `knex.schema.raw` function before?

Comment: Also it should have been enough to use knex.raw only in the last part of the query, where CASE is used. `.update({ isDeleted: knex.raw("CASE WHEN (x.Id <> OriginationAdmin.Brokers.Id) THEN 1 END")})`